# Generating JSON in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a column named as userId

```
|userId|
|  1   |
|  2   |
```

when I select this column I want to get value in form of json like this:-

```
user:{
  id:1
}
user:{
  id:2
}
```

is there any json function to do this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_build_object`:

```
WITH t (userid) AS (
  VALUES (1),(2)
)
SELECT json_build_object('user',json_build_object('id',userid)) 
FROM t;
   json_build_object   
-----------------------
 {"user" : {"id" : 1}}
 {"user" : {"id" : 2}}
(2 rows)
```

Comment: { "user" : 1, "user" : 1} this is the result.. not exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: @a_dog_with_no_master nested `json_build_object` might do the trick.. check the edit :)